# discord.py - How should I use on_reaction_add?

Tags: python, discord.py

My `on_reaction_add` seems to be not working. Here's my code:

```py
import discord
import asyncio
import datetime

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as', client.user)
    print('( name =', client.user.name, ', id =', client.user.id, ')')
    activity = discord.Game(name="&b help")
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.activity, activity=activity)


@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    await channel.send('test')
```

There is no error.
Why does not it work?

Comment: Hi, in order to help you with your question please follow [mcve]. Adding expected results will also help.

Comment: Try sending a new message and then reacting to it.  Your bot will only execute this event for messages found in its internal cache, which means only the messages that were sent after it came online.  You can read more about this behavior in the documentation: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_reaction_add

Answer (score 2):

The event `on_reaction_add` is called when a message has a reaction added to it. If the message is not found in the internal message cache, then this event will not be called. The cache is cleared after every restart.